# cakephp cakedc between

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I'd like to use the 'between' example from cakedc, but just can't make sense out of it.

```
'range' => array('type' => 'expression', 'method' => 'makeRangeCondition', 'field' => 'Article.views BETWEEN ? AND ?'),
```

I have field qca_start in my table and want user to provide two values (from, to) and search for qca_start between from and to.

My controller:
(I've used other simpler searches without problem. (employee_id works just fine here)

```
public $presetVars = array(
    array('field' => 'employee_id', 'type' => 'value'),
    array('field' => 'qca_start', 'type' => 'value') // not sure what type to use here for between search.
```

};
The field on my table is qca_start, not user how would i name the presetVar for this?

On my model

```
public $filterArgs = array(
array('name' => 'employee_id', 'type' => 'value'),
    'range' => array('type' => 'expression', 'method' => 'makeRangeCondition', 'field' => 'Article.views BETWEEN ? AND ?'),
```

);

I don't know how to format this for filterArgs:

```
'range' => array('type' => 'expression', 'method' => 'makeRangeCondition', 'field' => 'Article.views BETWEEN ? AND ?'),
```

I want qca_start to be between search values One and Two.

Can you help?

Comment: I've tried to use their Search Plugin once, but gave up. I believe those guys' CakePHP mindset is above mine. However, I plan on coming back to try it again.... soon!

Answer (score 1):

a copy/paste from the answer i gave @ [CakeDC Plugin Search Between Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098172/cakedc-plugin-search-between-dates)

in model :

```
        'creationDateBetween'       => array(
            'type'      => 'expression',
            'method'    => 'CreationDateRangeCondition',
            'field'     => 'MODEL.creationdate BETWEEN ? AND ?',
        ),

public function CreationDateRangeCondition($data = array()){
    if(strpos($data['creationDateBetween'], ' - ') !== false){
        $tmp = explode(' - ', $data['creationDateBetween']);
        $tmp[0] = $tmp[0]."-01-01";
        $tmp[1] = $tmp[1]."-12-31";
        return $tmp;
    }else{
        return array($data['creationDateBetween']."-01-01", $data['creationDateBetween']."-12-31");
    }
}
```

in view : note that i'm using a slider for year range

```
    echo $this->Form->input('creationDateBetween', 
    array(
        'label'     => __('Creation date between X and Y'),
        'div'       => false,
        'style' => 'border: 0; color: #49AFCD; font-weight: bold;'
    )
);

?><div id="creationDateBetweenSlider" style="padding:0;"></div><?php
```

---

```
<script>
$(function() {


    var     creationDateBetweenSlider = $( "#creationDateBetweenSlider" ),
        institutionCreationDateBetween  = $( "#MODELCreationDateBetween" ), 

lock = 0;

creationDateBetweenSlider.slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1900,
                max: 2050,
                values: [ 2000, 2013 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    MODELCreationDateBetween.val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                }
            });
        if(lock != 0) MODELCreationDateBetween.val( creationDateBetweenSlider.slider( "values", 0 ) + " - " + creationDateBetweenSlider.slider( "values", 1 ) );

lock = 1;

    });
</script>
```

waiting for feedback to see if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documenation @ https://github.com/cakedc/search

> 'expression' type useful if you want to add condition that will
>   generate by some method, and condition field contain several parameter
>   like in previous sample used for 'range'. Field here contains
>   'Article.views BETWEEN ? AND ?' and **Article::makeRangeCondition
>   returns array of two values**.

So just return 2 values in your method:

```
public function makeRangeCondition() {
    ...
    return array($from, $to);
}
```

They will automatically replace the two ? in this order then.